# New-LocalUser created while password complexity is not met

Tags: powershell

Consider the following code:

```
$params = @{
    Name        = 'testUser1'
    Password    = (ConvertTo-SecureString '3' -AsPlainText -Force)
    ErrorAction = 'Stop'
}
New-LocalUser @params
```

When the "Local Security Policy" for the password complexity is enabled the code above should fail. This seems to be the case but the user account is still created. Is this a bug in Windows?

Comment: Hm, I would at least also expect that the code should failed due to the local security policy

Comment: The funny thing is the error thrown is `Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of the domain.`. This seems like it's first created and only then will the password be set.

Comment: Yes, weird.. I also would have thought that would be reason enough to not create the user at all.. Does adding `-WarningAction Stop` make it behave like it should?

Comment: No Theo, that doesn't change the outcome I'm afraid.

Comment: Question 2: `ErrorAction Stop` lets code enter a `catch` block on errors (also non-terminating ones). Your example code does not wrap the `New-LocalUser` command inside a `try{..} catch{..}` block. What if you try with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

Yes, it might be a bug that your user account *half-way* exists after a failed creation due to an uncomplex password. The source code first creates a user account and then sets its password. Furthermore, it intends to delete a *half-way* created user account, but it obviously doesn't.

## Explanation

Let's have a look at the source code (relative to commit `658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b`):

1. [`New-LocalUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser) is implemented in [`NewLocalUserCommand.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Commands/NewLocalUserCommand.cs). In [line 262](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Commands/NewLocalUserCommand.cs#L262), [`CreateLocalUser()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L815) from [`Sam.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs) is called:

   ```
   user = sam.CreateLocalUser(user, Password, PasswordNeverExpires.IsPresent);
   ```

   So nothing special here.
2. [`CreateLocalUser()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L815) from [`Sam.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs) calls [`CreateUser()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L1231) on [line 819](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L819) in the same file:

   ```
   internal LocalUser CreateLocalUser(LocalUser user, System.Security.SecureString password, bool setPasswordNeverExpires)
   {
       context = new Context(ContextOperation.New, ContextObjectType.User, user.Name, user);

       return CreateUser(user, password, localDomainHandle, setPasswordNeverExpires);
   }
   ```

   Nothing special here.
3. Now [`CreateUser()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L1231) creates the user first without a password in [line 1248](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L1248) and later sets the password for the already existing user and also additional info in [line 1264](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L1264):

   ```
   status = SamApi.SamCreateUser2InDomain(domainHandle,
       ref str,
       (int) SamApi.USER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT,
       Win32.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,
       out userHandle,
       out grantedAccess,
       out relativeId);
   Marshal.DestroyStructure<UNICODE_STRING>(buffer);
   Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
   buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
   ThrowOnFailure(status);

   // set the various properties of the user. A SID is required because some
   // operations depend on it.
   userInfo.SID = RidToSid(domainHandle, relativeId);

   SetUserData(userHandle, userInfo, UserProperties.AllCreateable, password, PasswordExpiredState.NotExpired, setPasswordNeverExpires);
   ```

   This explains, why a user account is created even if the password complexity is not met: The password gets set later.

If you look further into the source code, you will see a `catch` block, that deletes the user in case something goes wrong. So it is indeed weird, that your new user persists after being created with an uncomplex password. [`SetUserData()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L2184) and [`SetUserPassword()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L2580), both forward exceptions. So, everything fine so far. [`SetUserPassword()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/e3d8353e3cb815568ab896751821263735aa2964/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/Sam.cs#L2580) calls [`SamSetInformationUser()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/658837323599ab1c7a81fe66fcd43f7420e4402b/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/LocalAccounts/SamApi.cs#L452) from `samlib.dll`. I assume that the password complexity will be checked there. Unfortunaltely, `samlib.dll` is not open source as far as I know and we cannot look into that any further.

So yes, it might be a bug that your user account *half-way* exists after a failed creation due to an uncomplex password. The code intends to delete a *half-way* created user account, but it obviously doesn't.